# freemarker easy explanation of wrappers

Tags: templates, wrapper, freemarker

i started my own little project a few weeks ago and now I´m stuck at freemarker.

I want to generate the items and sitemap for openHAB2 home-automation out of a excel sheet which contains my knx-structure.
So I made the import with apache-poi, built a POJO data-model and now I wanted to generate the pages out of the model.
The thing is, that freemarker doesn´t understand my model.
It´s a combination of interfaces, abstract classes and, of course, the beans, which extend or implement the former ones and contains lists of more class-objects as variables which also contain more lists of members, but at the end no rocket-science :-).

Do I have to write a wrapper now for each of these beans, or is there a magic setting, that does the trick?

Comment: update: sorry, wasn´t all that I wanted to ask ..... the main thing is about interfaces and classes which others inherits from...
My problem is, that i can´t specify e.g ${user.name} in template when the class User inherits from Person, and the getName method is in parent-class Person ....

Comment: nobody who wants to answer ... ? this problem really annoys me :-(

Comment: Can you be more specific? Show a class that you ran into a problem with, show how you attempted to access it from the template, and what was the error message.

Comment: Also, if your question changes, then edit it (or delete it and start an entirely new question), rather than adding a comment to it. (Think about it, someone takes his time reading your question, then realizes in the comment below that it was outdated.)

Comment: Hi there, i found a pretty big bug in my code (not worth mentioning it here) .... I apologize for bothering you guys ..... cheers